# Logintoboggan- Providing the one-time login link in an admin view

Tags: users

Logintoboggan can be configured so that users are initially assigned an *unverified* role and only become authenticated users when they click the link in their e-mail for the first time.

However, sometimes users have trouble clicking the link (low technical ability, old cellphones that don't recognize the link, etc.)  For this reason, sometimes the admin needs to activate a user's account on behalf of that user.

I have a view of users with the *unverified* role and I would like to add the one-time login links to the view so that admins can simply click them.  Logintoboggan provides a token, `[user:one-time-login-url]`, but this token cannot be used in Views.

Is there some way I can show the link in Views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an ideal way to do this, but since I am using the Panels module to display user profiles, I created a new variant for unverified users and added a piece of custom content on the variant (with a visibility rule restricting it to admin users) that showed the validation token.

Then I added a link on the view to the user profile; this is two steps instead of one, but at least it is a working solution.